# Error in GUI program

Tags: python, python-2.7, livewires

I was making a GUI program which would display a text on the top right corner of the screen. But when I ran the program, the screen just closed after 1-2 seconds without displaying the text.

```
from livewires import games,color

my_screen = games.Screen(screen_width = 640,screen_height = 480,fps = 50)
wall = games.load_image("wall.bmp",transparent = False)
my_screen.set_background(wall)

games.Text(screen = my_screen ,x = 500, y = 30, text = "Score = 19874", color = color.black, size = 50)

my_screen.mainloop()
```